# How to position elements when resizing windows changes all of it?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have an image that has lines all through it because they are providing my borders for the display that I want, around the image has a border because it makes the whole thing appear as a table [don't ask, it's what I am required to do], but then I want to position links ontop of the image in all different spots, and when I position them, and then resize the window, they all move out of the boxes that are shown in the image underneath. I read about using child and parent, and making the child relation to the parent but that isn't working.

any help would be great, and i do not know much about this at all, hence why I am asking. 
Thanks :)

Comment: show us your code or prepare jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div class like this:

```
<div class="container">
     here is all Other things that u have written
</div>
```

and this div Of your should have width and heights and your code will work correctly after this.
and i wish that u have written those links with position : absolute; & top:0; & left:0; 
 + z-index: "a Number bigger than your images";
if this One didnt worked just write your code here :)

Comment: Everytime I write my code in, it won't let me submit it. 
but basically i have a div, which contains my image, 
and then lots of other divs that contain my text that i want on top, each will be in a different position, but when i resize the window, if it is positioned against the left hand side of the window, it changes the look of it all. basically i'm trying to make the links page of www.ladisputemusic.com, to see the page, first you have to press 'click here to open' and then it opens the page that i'm talking about. Thanks for your help!

Comment: for submiting your code in here , each line Of your code part must have 4 spaces from left border.
and the second part is :
when u use position:absolute u are positioning this One with the parent div which mean if u the resizing problem , u are positioning it with the browser width and heights. put your code here then i can see if i can help u , and if my answer is the right One that u want plz check it :)